Abstract Algebra Resources Focusing on Connections to Other Mathematical Branches
I wanna brush up on my algebra skills by connecting the standard definitions/theorems with other branches of mathematics and I would like to know some book, lecture notes or other references with that same goal.
To illustrate what I mean, consider the following:

In the great "A Course in the Theory of Groups" by Robinson, the author defines what a nilpotent group is, proves some standard results about them, and even gives some examples of such groups. That is not what I have in mind.
In this blog post, Professor Tao gives some motivation for nilpotent groups where he gives some examples of analytical/algebraic-geometrical nature for nilpotent groups. He also states some similarities between these examples and some nilpotent Lie groups, and their relation to nilpotent Lie Algebras. That is exactly what I have in mind.

Notice that some of the examples in Robinson's book are exactly the motivating example in Tao's post, i.e., the Heisenberg group. So, what Robinson's book fails to do for me is not explicitly stating the non-algebraic flavors of those examples (I know that this was not his goal, so no worries, Robinson).
In essence, I'm seeking abstract algebra learning materials that emphasize the interplay between algebra and other mathematical disciplines, so that I can better understand how Algebra fits (nicely) into the broader mathematical landscape.

Are you willing to learn category theory?

If it fits the purpose, hell yeah!

If you are willing to learn about division algebras, you have: Berhuy, Oggier: An Introduction to Central Simple Algebras and Their Applications to Wireless Communication
